# font missing! convert pdf to pdf/a

Tags: fonts, pdf-a

I am converting my thesis in pdf to pdf/a. I wrote my thesis in latex. However, I met problems after I used adobe to convert it into pdf/a file. The message is like this:
[image]

Could anybody help me fix this? Thanks a lot!:)

Comment: As PDF/A becomes a requirement in more institutions, the kind of problem faced by the author will also be faced by more and more (La)TeX users. Although `Acrobat Pro` & its `Preflight` utility are not TeX-based tools, they will increasingly be needed with PDFs that we produce. We need to become aware of the issues, and some of us may be able to give good answers—either in the way the LaTeX source is prepared, or in how best to use `Preflight` afterwards. Certainly I recently faced such issues. So I'm suggesting that this item be re-opened.